# Android hacking no longer work on XE12 (Settings.apk and Launcher2.apk)

Tags: google-glass

I got my glass around thanksgiving last year.  I downloaded Settings.apk and Launcher2.apk from www.glassxe.com.  My project needs to communication through Bluetooth data channel.  With these two apks, it works fine.

This week, I connected the glass to my PC and it started auto upgrade, after the upgrade (XE12 firmware), the above two apks no longer work.  I had to uninstall them.

I am wondering how can I make them work under XE12?
Or how can I downgrade back to early versions of firmware?

BTW, my platform is Win 7, and adb seems working, but fastboot not working after XE12 upgrade.

Thanks in advance,

Xd

Comment: I know the Settings.apk still works, download here: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/OpenQuartz/tree/master/third-party

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that if your application includes the the Settings Intent filter and you have it on your Glass with XE12 it will break the Settings Bundle -- when you tap on Settings no apps will show up and you won't be able to go to the regular settings options such as Wifi, Bluetooth etc. This seems to be new behaviour in XE12 -- previously in XE11 this wasn't a problem.

The solution is to remove the Settings Intent filter from your application and launch your application only from the Voice Trigger method documented here:

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/voice

Comment: Could you elaborate on this process?  Are you talking about editing the  settings.apk?  If so, which java file?